# Error 101: Network is unreachable when trying to update

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

My ubuntu browsing this normally can not access any site, more `apt-get update` and even `upgrade` this giving error as shown below, what could it be?

```
sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease [94,5 kB]
Hit:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                     
  Cannot initiate the connection to br.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801:82:80ff:8000::5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err:4 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to br.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801:82:80ff:8000::5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Err:5 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to br.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801:82:80ff:8000::5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
Downloading 94,5 kB in 2min 0s (786 B/s)
Reading package lists ... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to br.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801:82:80ff:8000::5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to br.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801:82:80ff:8000::5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to br.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2801:82:80ff:8000::5). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Ubuntu:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
```

Comment: Just in case someone has similar problem - in my case, there was a problem with my network. I did have internet access, but the adapter was not configured properly. Once I switched to wifi adapter, the _apt update_ ran smoothly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Have you tried changing the repository to the 'Main server'?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJUIN.png)

You can change it by opening 'Software & Updates' and selecting a different mirror.

From time to time the local repository mirrors go down so its always a good idea to check other ones ;)

I have also noticed that it is trying to connect via IPv6 which your router or ISP may not support. Have you tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method)?

Answer (score 3):

From the logs it seems that your machine is using IPv6 to connect to the internet.  It could be that your internet service provider does not support IPv6.  You can try disabling IPv6.

To do this system-wide, edit the file `/etc/default/grub` (for instance using `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`), and adding `ipv6.disable=1` to the value of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`.

In a default Ubuntu installation that line reads

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

so you change it to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash ipv6.disable"
```

Afterwards, first run `sudo update-grub`, then reboot.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 because of a single networking issue seems a little overkill.

Comment: @DavidFoerster agree, but since poster wasn't able to browse the web either, I reckoned that only forcing APT on IPv4 wouldn't cut it.

Comment: Good point I originally understood the part about browsing to mean the opposite since it's stated so weirdly.