# Ubuntu 18.04 showing error with sudo apt update: "Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 ... 101: Network is unreachable"

Tags: networking, apt, 18.04

I tried all of the solutions from similar question.

```
Err:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Err:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
  Could not connect to dl.google.com:80 (172.217.167.14). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80 (2404:6800:4002:80a::200e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/InRelease  Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.161). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.162). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.149). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Could not connect to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (91.189.88.152). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::14). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::17). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::21). - connect (101: Network is unreachable) Cannot initiate the connection to in.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1560:8001::11). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/InRelease  Could not connect to dl.google.com:80 (172.217.167.14). - connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to dl.google.com:80 (2404:6800:4002:80a::200e). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: `101: Network is unreachable` So do you have internet connection? Are you using a VPN or proxy? Are you behind a corporate/university firewall?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 101: Network is unreachable when trying to update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/844476/error-101-network-is-unreachable-when-trying-to-update) and [Why I do get error 101? How is my DNS involved?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334886/why-i-do-get-error-101-how-is-my-dns-involved)

Comment: Yes I'm using proxy.

Comment: @Thomas: It appears that the same issue occurs for IPv4 connections.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. What's the output of `ip a` and `for n in {in.,}archive.ubuntu.com; do for v in '' 6; do ping$v -c4 $n; done; done`? Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))