# Connection to ppa.launchpad.net not private?

Tags: apt, ppa

I have some PPAs added to my system (Ubuntu 20.04), and when I try to update I get errors like:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
```

And when I try to open that URL in my browser, I get this:
[image]

Anyone knows what the issue could be?

Thanks.

Comment: No issues : http://ppa.launchpad.net/oibaf/graphics-drivers/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease

Comment: Yes I know, otherwise half the Internet will already be in panic. But the question is why does it happen on my system/network?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because of the firewall of your ISP. I had the same issue, just use a VPN and check.

Comment: This is actually correct, the ISP was the problem so I contacted them and told them the problem and now all the issues are solved.